# How to access the database from instance IAM user in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-iam

I have created the IAM user in instance.

While create Cloud IAM user its showing below error message

```
Required
After you create a user account with Cloud IAM authentication, it will have no database privileges, so make sure permissions are granted as needed.
```

How to access the database from IAM user. And what permissions are required?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "created the IAM user in instance" by including the commands that you used.

Comment: Google provides a myriad of database services, which database service do you mean?

Comment: Google provides extensive documentation for IAM roles|permissions applicable to all of its services (including the databases). If you Google "IAM permissions for [service-name]", you'll usually get the Google defined list as a near top result. I encourage you to try that too.

Comment: This is the error I am getting while connecting from pgadmin                                                                                         

unable to connect to server:connection to server at "server ip" port 5432 failed FATAL:Cloud SQL IAM user
authentication failed for user "username" connection to server at "server ip"
,port 5432 failes FATAL: pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "client ip",user "abc@gmail.com, database "postgres",SSL olff

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and assume you're talking about a Cloud SQL instance since the problem you're discussing mentions user accounts and Cloud IAM Authentication which is mentioned by Cloud SQL when creating user accounts.

To access a Cloud SQL you need two things:

1. Cloud SQL Client or another Cloud SQL Role that allows instance connection
2. Cloud SQL Instance User Credentials *(May need to create a Cloud SQL user before you have these, and potentially grant specific permissions on your databases)*
3. The final step is to allow your connection in to the Cloud SQL Instance, there's 2 major ways to do so: Use the [Cloud SQL Auth Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy), or adding your IP to the [Cloud SQL Instance's Authorized Networks](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/authorize-networks). * If your Cloud SQL Instance requires SSL/TLS connections you'll also require [SSL Certs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/authorize-ssl) from your instance on top of authorized networks. The Cloud SQL Auth Proxy is inherently an SSL/TLS connection.

> NOTE: Actual access to your Database is not granted via IAM roles. The IAM roles are merely to manage who can **attempt** to connect to your Cloud SQL instance and management of your Cloud SQL Instance. The Cloud SQL Instance User Credentials provide you with actual access to your Cloud SQL instance databases.

After having both of the requirements needed for a connection you'll need to decide on how to connect to your Cloud SQL instance. There's a [variety of connection options](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-overview), you'll have to decide on whichever method best fits your current use case.

EDIT: Added step 3, utilizing Cloud SQL Auth Proxy or using authorized networks

Comment: This is the error I am getting while connecting from pgadmin                                                                                         

unable to connect to server:connection to server at "server ip" port 5432 failed FATAL:Cloud SQL IAM user
authentication failed for user "username" connection to server at "server ip"
,port 5432 failes FATAL: pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "client ip",user "abc@gmail.com, database "postgres",SSL olff

Comment: Hey @JanSeijerlin just updated my comment, there's one last thing you'll need to do, checkout step 3 above. Essentially you'll also need to use the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy when connecting or add your IP you're attempting to connect from to your Cloud SQL Instance's Authorized Networks.

Otherwise if that doesn't work, it might be your username/password/host IP are entered incorrectly. Potentially the wrong connection string is being used, or database name. 

One other question, how are you creating your user accounts? In the Cloud SQL Instance UI I presume?